# Deleting all tags of a certain type in emacs

Tags: xml, regex, emacs

I've got an XML file. Just reading that, I can tell you're excited.

Now there's a few tags in it that I want to completely remove:

```
<qwerty option=1>
<nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
<blue>sdfsdf</blue>
</qwerty>
```

This is a big file. How would I remove all of the tags `nmo` and `blue`, including their contents? In Emacs, or anything else my mac can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your xml file is well formed. And I assume also that contrary to your example your "real-life" data is a little bit more complicated than one tag per line (except for the root one). Otherwise do we agree it would be as simple as removing lines containing a given tag?

Here is a proposition for a function that could do the trick:

```
(defun my-remove-tag (tag)
  (save-excursion
     (let ((case-fold-search nil))
       (while (search-forward-regexp (concat "<" tag "[^\\>]*>"))
     (delete-region
      (match-beginning 0)
      (search-forward (concat "</" tag ">")))))))
```

Calling this function you may look for `nmo`, `blue` or `qwerty` tags, as so:

```
(my-remove-tag "nmo")
(my-remove-tag "qwerty")
```

The rationale is looking for a opening tag then look for the closing one, and delete everything in the middle. Attributes for a tag could go in the middle of the way, and this function deal with opening tag containing attributes.

The case sensitiveness is disabled and restored once the function is done. Also the Emacs Point is restored with the usual macro : `save-excusion`.

### Update

I removed the outer let. No need to restore the case-fold-search value by hand, the let binding simply shadows the global value, it is restored by by means of "unshadowing".

Comment: This won't work if the unwanted elements can nest inside one another, of course, but if that's not the case then it's fine (although if using this approach I'd be more inclined to do an interactive regexp replace of `<\(nmo\|blue\)\b.*?</\1>`

Comment: Yes. The non greedy version of the star is a nice trick. Useful comment.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs has commands for navigating symbolic expressions, or "sexps".  In `xml-mode`, the sexp navigation commands work on tags.  You can navigate to the opening `<`, press <kbd>C-M-f</kbd> (`forward-sexp`) to navigate to the end of the tag, or press <kbd>C-M-k</kbd> (`kill-sexp`) to kill it.  The variable `nxml-sexp-element-flag` controls whether you go the end of the opening tag (the default) or the end of the closing tag.  I prefer the latter.

To remove those tags, first set `nxml-sexp-element-flag` with <kbd>M-x customize-variable nxml-sexp-element-flag</kbd>.  Next, search for the tag you'd like to kill, move the point to the opening `<` and press <kbd>C-M-k</kbd>.  Wrap this all up in a macro, and repeat over the entire file until the search fails.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a more generic approach would be to use some more XML-oriented tool, like XSL(T) (don't be afraid, no one likes that), but it can come in handy if you have to work with XML (don't be afraid, no one likes that either).

So, here we go:

This is your XSL file (it copies all the stuff in the original XML and replaces the nodes you wanted to remove with empty lines. Finally, it prints it out, making it look somewhat prettier, then if you have it replaced using a regexp.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

  <!-- Copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Find any node named nmo or blue and replace it with nothing -->
  <xsl:template match="nmo | blue"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my example I used to test:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodes>
  <qwerty option="1">
    <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
    <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
  </qwerty>
  <nodes>
    <qwerty option="1">
      <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
      <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
    </qwerty>
  </nodes>
  <nodes>
    <qwerty option="1">
      <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
      <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
    </qwerty>
    <other node=""/>
    <nodes>
      <qwerty option="1">
        <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
        <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
      </qwerty>
      <qwerty option="1">
        <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
        <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
      </qwerty>
      <qwerty option="1">
        <nmo>sdfsdf</nmo>
        <blue>sdfsdf</blue>
      </qwerty>
    </nodes>
  </nodes>
</nodes>
```

And this is the output I'm receiving:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nodes>
  <qwerty option="1"/>
  <nodes>
    <qwerty option="1"/>
  </nodes>
  <nodes>
    <qwerty option="1"/>
    <other node=""/>
    <nodes>
      <qwerty option="1"/>
      <qwerty option="1"/>
      <qwerty option="1"/>
    </nodes>
  </nodes>
</nodes>
```

Notice how it also closed the `qwerty` nodes.

The command line to get this would be something like:

```shell
xsltproc ./remove-nodes.xsl ./nodes-to-be-removed.xml > result.xml
```

You could run it from Emacs' shell, or use any of Emacs' function to call it / create a process with it and so on. `man xsltproc` for more info - it's usage is really basic. It was installed on my Fedora, but I would imagine that due to widespread of XML around the world it would either be already installed on a Mac, or must be installable in some way.